# How can I programmaticaly submit the user edit form in Drupal 8?

Tags: 8, forms, authentication-authorization

I need to create a logout button in my app, and I do not know how to revoke simple_oauth tokens programmatically, but I have noticed if the user saves their profile form (form_id: "user_form") in Drupal, it revokes the user's access token.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to programmatically submit the form so I can do so in a logout endpoint for my app.

That is, unless someone can point me to the specific code that revokes a user's access token when the user edit form is saved, so I can fire that hook  more directly.

Because the oauth2_token table does not reference the associated user (auth_user_id is always zero), I don't know how to look up a token by UID for the purpose of revoking the token.  Thus, even though it seems like a hack, the only thing I can think to do is to try to submit the user edit form programmatically.

UPDATE: I was wrong about "auth_user_id is always zero".  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was mistaken when I said "auth_user_id" is always zero.  It isn't.  It contains the user's ID, as you would expect.  That makes this task fairly simple.  Here is the function for my logout endpoint:

```
public function logout($name = NULL) {

    if ($name) {
      $user = user_load_by_name($name);
      if ($user) {
        $uid = $user->id();

        $msg = 'User ' . $name . ' (uid: ' . $uid . ') logged out of app.';
        \Drupal::logger('orb_common')->notice($msg);

        // Not sure if it would be a better practice to set the status to zero, or delete.  In this example I delete the row.     
        $query = \Drupal::database()->delete('oauth2_token');
        $query->condition('auth_user_id', $uid);
        $query->execute();
      }
    }

    $response['data'] = [];
    $response['method'] = 'POST';

    return new JsonResponse($response);
  }
```

In my routing file I have...

```
orb_common.orb_common_logout:
  path: '/orb_common/logout/{name}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\orb_common\Controller\CommonController::logout'
    _title: 'Logout'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'edit activity entities'
```

The JsonResponse at the end of my logout function presumably isn't important in this case.  The main thing is to pass a UID or username to Drupal in the URL of the endpoint, and then delete/update the relevant row in the oauth2_token table.  At least, that is working in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Logging the user out through Drupal itself should revoke the user's access token.

Try invoking [`UserController::logout`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Controller%21UserController.php/function/UserController%3A%3Alogout/8.6.x).

Comment: This method calls user_logout(), which ends a Drupal session but has no impact on simple_oauth tokens.  I need to revoke the simple_oauth token for the user.

Comment: I apologize. I misunderstood. This seems to be a known issue with the module. Source: [#2945273](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_oauth/issues/2945273)

Comment: No worries.  I'm a participant in that issue, as it happens.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to submit the form programmatically, all you need to do is to call [user_logout()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_logout/8.5.x) in your logout API endpoint. This should invalidate all the session tokens.

FYI you should check the Drupal 8 REST API docs, there is a core endpoint for logging out current user. Check this URL below,

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/javascript-and-drupal-8-restful-web-services

Comment: The user_logout() function has no effect on simple_oauth access tokens, so I'm afraid this doesn't work.  The user_logout() function is a way to end Drupal browser sessions.